# Hurry someone to do something/hurry someone into doing something

Tags: meaning

Do these mean the same?

> 1 He hurried her to tell them the news.
>
> 2 He hurried her into telling them the news.

I heard an opinion that 1 is used when the action is already started. In a sense, the speaker urges someone to finish it. 2 means the speaker urges someone to start an action.

Is it true or not?

Comment: I don't think I would use 'hurry' like that at all. "He pestered her to tell them the news" and "He told her to hurry up and get to the point".

Comment: You may well not use it but one of the usages is mentioned here "https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hurry_1?q=hurry"  hurry somebody into doing something

Comment: The Ngram results for _hurried her to_ and _hurried her into_ all seem to refer to urging someone to go somewhere quickly, or carrying them there. I think another verb such as _urged her_ or _pressed her_ would be more suitable here.

Comment: Yes: "he hurried her **into** telling them the news" isn't like how you used it.

Comment: Kate Bunting, do you agree with the nuances I submitted?

Comment: https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3192393/Male-model-spiked-clubber-s-drink-MDMA-Kensington-Roof-Gardens-told-great-sex.html  The woman said Riches hurried her to finish her glass of wine

Comment: To me _He hurried her into [doing something]_ suggests _Because he was hurrying her so much, she [did something]_, implying that she wouldn't have done it if she had been thinking straight. (NB Don't forget the @ if you want people to pick up on comments addressed to them!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence means he tried to get her to tell the news faster. It's *unclear if he succeeded*, so the sentence is just about the effort.

In the second sentence, the preposition "into" means *he succeeded* in getting her to tell the news faster.